# Condition to group rows in dataframes python into an interval

Tags: python, dataframe

I succeeded to extract data into a dataframe, but I don't know how can I manage it to detect values which are in the same range and mean them.

Here is a simple version of my data:

```
import pandas as pd

matrix = [[0,11,0],[0.99,25,1],[1.99,17,1],[0.1,6,0],[0.88,9,1] ]

data=pd.DataFrame(matrix,columns=['distance in mm','Lithium','Calcium'])
```

Then I want to group in another dataframe rows that have a common distance in mm of +/- 0.2 mm, calculate the average and standard deviation.

I wish an output similar to this:

[image]

Should I create a dictionary which will contain mean and std deviation values?

In the dataframe call data you can find that the first column is named 'distance in mm'. I would like to measure the interval of each single row and unify the row that share the same interval by calculating the mean and the standard deviation. I tried : `data['distance_bins'] = pd.cut(data['distance in mm'], np.arange(0, data['distance in mm'].max() + 0.2, 0.2))`

The idea consists to group data (analytical replicates) not using labelling but relative position on a sample.

Then I tried: `groups = data.groupby('distance_bins')`. But after that I'm completely lost, since I am not familiar with object which has been created by the function groupby – `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`.

Comment: Note on the `Series` object: that is basically a single column of a DataFrame. But you can also just read up on `Series` in the Pandas documentation, which has lots of examples of using Series, and combining a Series into a DataFrame.

Comment: When you mention grouping or clustering, do you prefer/want explicit (predefined) bins, or rather dynamically created groups. The second option makes it a much harder problem: for example, how would you group 0.11, 0.20, 0.32, 0.39, 0.51, 0.60, and why that way (what's the mechanism behind it)?

Comment: For my personal purpose, I don't need a dynamical range of bins, just predefined will be enough.

Comment: You may want to add that explicitly to your question, for clarity.

Comment: For my personal purpose, I don't need a dynamical range of bins (interval ?), just predefined will be enough. Data came from analysis that I perform at distances higher than the wanted interval. I believe that this method will group replicates together (replicates have been analysed at roughly the same distance).  
I know that my data will be in the predefined intervals, but for more complexe data has you mentioned in example, this strategy will not be relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

1. Create your `bins` based on the minimum and maximum values in the first column
2. Next, your `pd.cut` to cut your column based on the bins. In this case, you are including left and excluding right `[left, right)`
3. Then, define your aggregations in a dictionary and groupby your data based on the `groups` defined above, while passing the aggregations to `.agg()` method.
4. Finally, (Optionally), filter out the rows with nan values based on first column. You can also rename the index for readibility.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create bins with +/- 0.2
mini = data['distance in mm'].min()
maxi = data['distance in mm'].max()
bins = np.arange(mini, maxi+0.4, 0.4)

# Cut into groups
groups = pd.cut(data['distance in mm'], bins, right=False)

# Aggregate using groupby
aggr = {'distance in mm':['mean', 'std'], 
        'Lithium':['mean','std'], 
        'Calcium':['mean', 'std']}
grouped = data.groupby(groups).agg(aggr)

# Filter out rows with nans in first column (OPTIONAL)
filtered = grouped[grouped[('distance in mm','mean')].notna()] #<-- Optional
filtered.index.name = 'bins'                                   #<-- Optional

print(filtered)
```

```
           distance in mm           Lithium            Calcium     
                     mean       std    mean        std    mean  std
bins                                                               
[0.0, 0.4)          0.050  0.070711     8.5   3.535534     0.0  0.0
[0.8, 1.2)          0.935  0.077782    17.0  11.313708     1.0  0.0
[1.6, 2.0)          1.990       NaN    17.0        NaN     1.0  NaN
```

Comment: Wouldn't this put two values that are within 0.2mm, like 0.39 and 0.41 mm, into two separate bins, and not group them together?

Comment: the binning of +/- 0.2 has to be defined between some range. as it so happens, the 0.4 sized bins which OP is referring to start from 0.0 which is the minimum in the data. As the expected output matches with this output as well.

Comment: OP mentions "clustering" however, the attempted code approaches they have are all fixed binning based, which means they are not looking for an ML/dynamic prog method to solve this.

Comment: Indeed; I just wanted to make it explicit. I put the question to the OP as well.